# Docker build outputs not working in Bitbucket pipelines

Tags: docker, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to use the [custom build output](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#custom-build-outputs) within docker to export some files in to the build environment for artifacts but even though the files seem to be outputted there's nothing I can find in the build agent.

For simplicity here's a cutdown version of a dockerfile that uses a scratch image as the final image with a single `message` file.

```
FROM debian as build
RUN echo "Hello World" > message

FROM scratch as final
COPY --from=build message .
```

And here's an example of the scripts run for out ci pipeline within the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```yaml
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  default:
     - step:
        name: Build
        script:
          - docker build -o build-output .
          - ls
          - find / -name "build-output" -type d
        services:
          - docker
```

Here's the log output from Bitbucket pipelines.

```sh
Images used:
    build : docker.io/atlassian/default-image@sha256:d8ae266b47fce4078de5d193032220e9e1fb88106d89505a120dfe41cb592a7b
+ docker build -o build-output .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  65.02kB
Step 1/4 : FROM debian as build
latest: Pulling from library/debian
627b765e08d1: Pulling fs layer
627b765e08d1: Verifying Checksum
627b765e08d1: Download complete
627b765e08d1: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:cc58a29c333ee594f7624d968123429b26916face46169304f07580644dde6b2
Status: Downloaded newer image for debian:latest
 ---> 0980b84bde89
Step 2/4 : RUN echo "Hello World" > message
 ---> Running in dfcb5471840d
Removing intermediate container dfcb5471840d
 ---> 245eb3333d6c
Step 3/4 : FROM scratch as final
 ---> 
Step 4/4 : COPY --from=build message .
 ---> a8805c31d962
Successfully built a8805c31d962

+ ls
Dockerfile
bitbucket-pipelines.yml

+ find / -name "build-output" -type d
```

As you can see the `build-output` directory is nowhere to be seen!

Here's a public build with the whole example - https://bitbucket.org/kev_bite/dockerbuildoutput/addon/pipelines/home#!/results/2

Comment: I'm wondering if this is possible too!